# Class not being added to NSMutableArray.. why?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a class defined with five (5) properties.  I want to take those properties and place them in a NSMutableArray (listOfSites).  This is my code:

```
FMResultSet *rs = [fmdb executeQuery: @"SELECT SITE_ID, SITE_DESC, DATE FROM SiteData WHERE SITE_ID <> '0'"];
while([rs next])  {
    sArray *sa = [[sArray alloc] init];
    sa.sSiteID = [rs stringForColumnIndex:0];
    sa.sJobDesc = [rs stringForColumnIndex:1];
    sa.sJobDate = [rs stringForColumnIndex:2];

    [listOfSites addObject:sa];  //  add class object to array
}
[fmdb close];
```

The sArray (not an array, but the name of the class) has the correct content, but the "addObject: sa" message does NOT place the class into the class.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:  declaration of "listOfSites":

```
@interface slSQLite : NSObject  {

    sqlite3 *dataBase;  //  declare pointer to database
    UILabel *status;
    BOOL newFlag;
    int siteCount;
    int seqNbr;
    NSDate *date;
    NSString *dbCmd;
    NSMutableArray *listOfSites;  //  populated by sqlite

}
```

Initialization of "listOfSites":

```
@implementation slAppDelegate  {   }

@synthesize window = _window;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  {

    slSQLite *sqlite = [[slSQLite alloc] init];  //  allocate class
    [sqlite checkForDatabase];  //  check for database

    NSMutableArray *listOfSites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: Show your code where `listOfSites` is declared and initialized.

Comment: Agreed, can you add to your question where listOfSites is declared? You are also leaking the sArray sa. You should release sa after you add it to listOfSites.

Comment: Darren: I'm using ARC...

Comment: Add a line before the addObject `NSLog(@"sa %@", [sa description]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different variables named `listOfSites`. The first one is a local variable in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  {
    //...
    NSMutableArray *listOfSites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //...
}
```

The second one is an instance variable one the class `slSQLite`:

```
@interface slSQLite : NSObject {
    // ...
    NSMutableArray *listOfSites;  //  populated by sqlite
}
```

When you initialize the variable `listOfSites` that is in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,, the there variable that is in `slSQLite` remains unchanged and non initialized.

So you should initialize the array before using it:

```
listOfSites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while([rs next])  {
    sArray *sa = [[sArray alloc] init];
    sa.sSiteID = [rs stringForColumnIndex:0];
    sa.sJobDesc = [rs stringForColumnIndex:1];
    sa.sJobDate = [rs stringForColumnIndex:2];

    [listOfSites addObject:sa];
}
NSLog(@"The array listOfSites contains %d items, listOfSites.count);
```

---

PS. `sa` is an object and not a class. It is an instance of the class `sArray`.

Comment: sch:  I posted where I initialized the array in app DidFinishLaunching

Comment: See my edited answer. Your problem is that you initialized a different array. Even if the two array have the same name, they are different: one is a local variable and one is an instance variable of the class `slSQLite`. And when you obtained *"listOfSites" contains 0 items"*, did you initialize the array as I said, or you just added the `NSLog` statement?

Comment: IT WORKS!  Thank you so much... I got confused (it's easy for me! :D )

Comment: sch: one more question: now that it's working, how do I address listOfSites from another class?

Comment: It has to be a property and not just an instance variable. Post a new question if you need more help with that.